# jQuery. Convert string to jQuery object and remove link (a) tag

Tags: jquery, tags

I want to remove a href tag from string. 
From this:

"[google](http://www.google.com) okss strogns**strong**"

To this: "google okss strogns**strong**"

I already tried:

```
function removeElements(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>" + text + "</div>");
    wrapped.find(selector).remove();
    return wrapped.html();
}
var newContent = removeElements(tinyMCE.get('opt3').getContent(), 'a');
```

But get error: Cannot read property 'find' of null.

Maybe somebody knows other approaches?

Comment: Could you provide a working copy in Fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [unwrap](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap) the [contents](https://api.jquery.com/contents) of the passes selector so

```
function removeElements(text, selector) {
    var wrapped = $("<div>/", {
        html: text
    });
    wrapped.find(selector).contents().unwrap();
    return wrapped.html();
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/15qcdpqy/)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure jQuery is loaded on your page?

Also, try using `.unwrap()` (https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) instead of `.remove()`

Comment: And unless you want your result being wrapped in div-Tags you can convert your string into html by using jQuery's `parseHTML()`.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a div that contains your text

```
<div class="test">
   <a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">google</a> " okss strognsstrong
</div>
```

what you can do is use the [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method that gets the actual text that is included in the `#test` div and then by using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) prepopulate the `div`

```
$("#test").html($('#test').text());
```

The above line of code will produce this:

```
<div class="test">
    google okss strognsstrong
</div>
```